# Point a subdomain to a minecraft server

Tags: dns, port, minecraft, cname

I'm trying to get my minecraft server to be reachable through my domain name, as opposed to needing to connect with the IP and port.
Because I want to host multiple servers, it would be ideal if I could tie a subdomain to a port, so then people could just connect to minecraft.sandwich247.com and be in to the main server, or somethingelse.sandwich247.com to go to a different server.

On my dns provider's website, I've created an A record with

`Domain    Target`     
`minecraft 77.99.72.13`

I've created an SRV record with the server of

`Domain`  `_minecraft._tcp.minecraft.sandwich247.com`

`Target`  `minecraft.sandwich247.com`

`Priority`  `0`

`Weighting`  `5`

`Port`
`25565`

In minecraft, if I try to connect to 77.99.72.13:65535, it works fine.

If I try to connect to minecraft.sandwich247.com it does *not*

Running `nslookup minecraft.sandwich247.com` gives

```
Server:  194.168.4.100
Address: 194.168.4.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:    minecraft.sandwich247.com
Address: 77.88.72.13
```

If I run `nslookup -type=SRV _minecraft._tcp.sandwich247.com` then I get

```
Sever:   192.168.4.100
Address: 194.168.4.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_minecraft._tcp.sandwich247.com service = 0 5 25565 minecraft.sandwich247.com

Authoritative answers can be found from:
minecraft.sandwich247.com internet address = 77.99.72.13
```

If I run `nslookup -type=SRV _minecraft._tcp.minecraft.sandwich247.com` then I get

```
Server: 194.168.4.100
Address: 194.168.4.100#53

** server can't find _minecraft._tcp.minecraft.sandwich247.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I have no idea what that 194.168.4.100 IP address is (possibly my ISP?)

If I use a port checker to see if minecraft.sandwich247.com has port 25565 open, then it says it's closed, but checking with the IP says it's open.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 194.168.4.100 is a Virgin Media Public IP, somewhere in London. So is 77.99.72.13

Comment: In fact 194.168.4.100 is Virgin's default DNS address

Comment: Very strange, do you think I need to contact them to get this sorted?

Comment: I honestly don't know - the address looked familiar but I couldn't remember why, so i went to look it up. It was only a few minutes later I realised why I knew it … I'm on Virgin too ;)

Comment: There is really only one possibility: you actually did _not_ create the DNS record you think you created. Check your SRV record again.

Comment: see, that's what I was thinking, but I've quadruple quintuple checked and I *think* it's okay?

https://i.imgur.com/ywH8EZy.png
https://i.imgur.com/MPVbIUj.png

Comment: It’s not. The entry is/was for `_minecraft._tcp`, not `_minecraft._tcp.minecraft`.

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT!

I did everything correctly, it's just my IP had changed from ending in 13 to ending in 12 :facepalm:

Looks like I need to double check the cron job I have set which calls the API for my DNS Provider which *should* be automatically updating the IP address it links to :/